# apply normalisation on groupBy data in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

DataFrame columns:

```
['PercentSalaryHike', 'Attrition', 'EmployeeCountFraction']
```

After Grouping by first two columns:
EmployeeCount shows the ***fraction of people*** whose attrition is ***'yes'*** and rest ***'No'*** for that particular ***PercentSalaryHike***

[image: DataFrame]

After Resetting index, DataFrame looks like:

[image]

What I want exactly is to apply normalisation to simplify DataFrame.
Should look like:

```
PercentSalaryHike   Attrition-Yes    Attrition-No

11                    0.195238       0.804762
12                    0.166667       0.833333
13                    0.837321       0.163351
..
..
..
```

The sample I have given applies groupBy on 2 fields. I want a general solution by which data grouped by n number of fields is normalised in such manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) for reshape data, then [`add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html),  [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and last [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df = df['EmployeeCountFraction'].unstack()
                                .add_prefix('Attrition-')
                                .reset_index()
                                .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df)
   PercentSalaryHike  Attrition-No  Attrition-Yes
0                 11      0.804762       0.195238
1                 12      0.833333       0.166667
2                 13      0.837321       0.163351
```

Comment: That's it :) . You are the one daily answering :D . Thanks buddy

Comment: the .add_prefix is somewhat specific, what if I grouped the data by more umber of fields ?

Comment: the best is create some sample, but it should work too. But if need unstack by multiple levels like `.unstack([1,2])` then get multiindex as columns and need something like `df.columns = df.columns.map('-'.join)` for flattening to columns names.